# Wifi issue on Lenovo c940

Tags: wireless, lenovo, blacklist

I have a problem with my wifi on Lenovo C940. The usual fix that is circulating for older generations (c930) with blacklisting ideapad_laptop wont do the trick.. Is there any other way to tackle this problem?

Comment: "I have a problem..." What kind of problem? Do you have a wireless interface? Does it try and fail to connect? Does it scan and see networks? Does the Airplane Mode button or switch do nothing? Please provide sufficient additional details so that we may proceed further. Welcome to Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: [Argh - can't comment until I get a higher reputation.] I going to get a Yoga C940 soon so I'm very interested in the resolution of this issue. I note that there are two possible WiFi solutions in the US:
Intel® 802.11AC (2 x 2) & Bluetooth® 5.0
Intel® 802.11AX (2 x 2) & Bluetooth® 5.0 Please also say which you have.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3; rfkill list` terminal command.

Comment: A kernel update did the trick! I'll let you know what WiFi card there is in mine. If there is anything else you wanna know about the laptop and my experience with ubuntu on it then feel free to send me a pm!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve all the issues with a kernel update (5.3). So if you get this laptop I would recommend having a external network card during the installation process.

Comment: any update on this? I tried with a kernel 5.3.7 but still the same issue, the wifi get not recognized, means the card get not listed at all

Comment: It works fine under kernel 5.3.0-17 generic for me. I still have a problem with the speakers(a bit quiet and tinny compared to in windows) but aside from that everything works

Comment: so you just installed ubuntu 19.10 and then did a kernel update to 5.3?

Comment: Yea exactly, so youll need an external network card for the update process

Comment: OK this worked, I am using Kernel 5.3.7 now. I have Just the Problem left that the touchpad is not working after resuming from hibernate. Which Kernel Do you use?

Comment: I have the C940 15" (15-IRH) and ran into both these problems (wifi issues and touchpad not working after resume). For wifi, I found if you disable power management via iwconfig in Linux it works for both sleep and hibernate. Windows hibernate (if you dual boot), however will break wifi. Disable it. To fix you need to go into the bios and toggle secure boot on then off (reboot in between). That somehow resets the card. To fix the touchpad after resume from hibernate, just put the computer to sleep and wake it up again. This happens in both Linux and Windows and fixes it in both places for me.

Answer (score 0):

I just bought a C940 from Best Buy.  It is working better than I expected.  I didn't have to do anything to get WiFi to work after installing Fedora 31.  (I'm now running kernel 5.3.8).  WiFi even works after suspend.

Answer (score 0):

Wifi worked on my lenovo c940 out of the box.

I installed ubuntu 19.10 nightly, so if you are reading this before it is fully released, instead of upgrading kernel of 19.04 through external network card you can download nightly release of ubuntu that would include the most recent kernel.